# Format string in mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have string values on my object formatted in Markdown. When mapping to my `ObjectViewModel` type, I will need to format the Markdown towards HTML. 
As I understand it, I could use a `Resolver` and the `ResolveUsing` when mapping - But I got a lot of different string properties needed to go through the procedure and it seems he implementation of the `Resolver` decides the properly not at the `CreateMap`.

```
.ForMember(m => m.Description, o => o.MapFrom(f => f.Description))
```

this will just Map the values.

Are there any way doing something special on a per Property basis, like :

```
.ForMember(m => m.Description, o => o.ConvertUsing<MarkDownToHtmlConverter>(f => f.Description))
```

Comment: you can use  `aftermap`
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that jump to mind straight away:

1) ValueConverter

```
public class MarkDownToHtmlConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Convert to HTML here
        string html = sourceMember;
        return html;
    }
}

cfg.CreateMap<Entity, EntityViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Description, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new MarkDownToHtmlConverter()));
```

2) AfterMap

```
public class HtmlToMarkdownAction : IMappingAction<Entity, EntityViewModel>
{
    public void Process(Entity source, EntityViewModel destination)
    {
        destination.Description = source.Description; // Convert to HTML
    }
}


cfg.CreateMap<Entity, EntityViewModel>()
    .AfterMap<HtmlToMarkdownAction>();
```

My opinion on this though is that the conversion should take place somewhere else at display time, in Razor for instance. Doesn't seem like the job of a mapper to do this type of conversion... this is only my opinion though.